Two-dimensional synthetic spectra for roughness
I'm trying to generate two-dimensional frequency spectra representing the roughness of a rocky surface. My main problem is that, although the spectra resemble real spectra (in absolute value), when I apply the ifft2, the result does not look good.
For example, I have a rock sample (Fig.1), to which I apply the fft2 and obtain Fig.2, and then apply the ifft2 and get Fig.1 again. This works fine.
If I generate a synthetic spectrum (Fig.3), when I apply the ifft2, I get Fig.4, which is not suitable at all. There are some shortcomings here, such as my synthetic spectrum only having a real part, and all frequencies are positive.
That's why I've tried to minimize the problem as much as possible, in order to compare between the "real" and "synthetic" cases.
From the spectrum of the real sample, Fig.2, I only keep the real part and the highest frequencies (Fig.5). I consider the imaginary part to be zero. I read the spectrum from Excel, then decenter it (np.fft.ifftshift) and apply the ifft2. When I apply the ifft2, I get a reasonable surface (Fig.6).
With the synthetic spectrum, I do the same: I consider the data from Fig.7 to be the real part, and there is no imaginary part. When I apply the ifft2, I get Fig.8.
In Fig.8, the problem from Fig.4 begins to appear: very high values at the edges and the rest of the surface becomes smooth.
Comparing the values of Fig.5 and Fig.7, I think the problem may come from the sign of the frequencies and the energy of each frequency component, which for the real case are compensated and for the synthetic case are not. But I have no idea what the real problem is and how to solve it. If you can help me with this reduced case, I would appreciate it.
Any help is welcome. Thank you!”
Fig.1 
Fig.2 
Fig.3 
Fig.4 
Fig.5 
Fig.6 
Fig.7 
Fig.8 

The fft is complex not real. By discarding the phase you create a "zero phase" spectrum, the IFFT of which also real and symmetric around the lower left corner which is exactly what you get. I strongly suggest starting with a 1D FFT first and once you got your arms around that you can move up to 2D.

Thanks, Hilmar. Yes, I spent some time in 1D but probably not enough. In the two reduced cases, I only use the real part of the spectra. In both cases, there is symmetry, but I don’t understand why in the first case the final surface seems normal, while in the second case it seems so exaggerated at the edges. The difference arises from the values in Fig. 5 and Fig. 6, but I recognize that my knowledge in DSP is very limited.

The axes are probably mislabeled. For the 2D FFT the point [x=0,y=0] is always the lower left corner. If you want  [x=0,y=0] in the center you need to circularly shift your data

Thank you very much, Hilmar. I centered the spectra after calculation, so now the origin is not in the lower left corner but in the center. I do this with the command fftshift(zi_fft (I also center the frequencies). Since I provide a centered spectrum before applying the inverse transform, I have to decenter it. Fig. 2, 3, 6, 7 are centered spectra, from which, after decentering, I obtain the surfaces Fig. 1 and 6 (fine) and Fig. 4 and 8 (not fine). I believe that if there were an axis error, it should fail all the time and not just in the synthetic spectra.
